# Why do I need to set target folder as source folder? How was the project compiled for the first time when "target" wasn't cretaed?

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, maven

I have an existing maven project (IDE used: Sprint Test Tool) and I have very very limited help available around it. I'm new to maven, java and stuff (I know basic java and have done automation in java but haven't worked on full-fledged java projects) and I have to figure our all of this project more or less by myself.
I was trying to compile the package but it shows errors in main\src\java that "Messages can NOT be resolved" over some code of this sort: Messages.. I searched through the folders and found there's just one Messages.java file (with that method definition in it) in sub-folders of the "target" folder in the project. So, I was asked to add the path/folder of this sub-folder as source folder and the error was gone.

I believe whole of "target" is created when a maven project is compiled/packaged. And, adding a path to the source folder indexes the path and makes it available for compliation/packaging. So, I'm wondering how the project was compiled and packaged at the first place.
I do see Messages.properties in src\main\resources\folders..\Messages.properties and the methods defined in Messages.java seem to have some relationship with this properties file.

I searched through net but couldn't find an answer. Could stack please help me here?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please supply the <plugins> section of your pom.xml file. You are correct that as a general rule, the target/ dir is generated by Maven to store build outputs therefore should not be a dependency for your build.

Answer (score 0):

The info you've provided is somewhat sparse, so it will help if you can supply a snippet of your pom.xml file - specifically the `<plugins>` section, and the directory structure of your project from the top level, especially the location of this `Messages` files.

You are correct that the `target` dir is created dynamically by Maven to store the output of your build, and therefore nothing in its contents should be a dependency of your build.

The most likely case is that your build has some sort of code generators (perhaps an Ant task or some Maven plugin) running prior to the `compile` phase, and that is what is generating the `Messages.java` file on which you depend.

Assuming that `Messages.java` is generated, then the solution is to have it sit in `src/main/gen/` directory and add that dir to your build path (and remove target).

**Clean option: might not be possible**

If you can figure out which plugin is creating `Messages.java`, and if it's possible to modify its output path, then that's the simplest option - reconfigure it to write to `src/main/gen/` instead of `target/`.

**Dirty but reliable option**

It may be that the above is not feasible for whatever reason. Then simply copy the `Messages.java` file from `target/` to `src/main/gen/` during the `pre-compile` phase in your pom file:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>mojo.codehaus.org</groupId>
    <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.2</version>
    <configuration>
        <executable>cp</executable>
        <arguments>
            <argument>target/Messages.java</argument>
            <argument>src/main/gen/Messages.java</argument>
        </arguments>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Hope that helps.