# Can anyone explain me the package structure of default spring boot application that is provided by spring starter project?

Tags: spring, eclipse, spring-boot, maven

What is the target folder, what is mvnw and mvnw.cmd file and what is src folder?

[image: Refrence Image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. target: the tools will build and create intermediate and output files, say java `.class` files. That will be put there. [more info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26812967/why-do-i-need-to-set-target-folder-as-source-folder-how-was-the-project-compile)
2. mvnw and mvnw.cmd are wrappers of `maven`. see [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38723833/what-is-the-purpose-of-mvnw-and-mvnw-cmd-files).

Answer (score 2):

That is the [default structure](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html) for a Maven project and this structure is also used as a defacto standard (Gradle uses it as well for instance).

> The `target` directory is used to house all output of the build.
>
> The `src` directory contains all of the source material for building the project, its site and so on. It contains a subdirectory for each type: `main` for the main build artefact, `test` for the unit test code and resources, `site` and so on.

Source: The Maven guide (see link above).

The `mvnw` script and `.mvnw` directory (currently hidden) is for the [Maven Wrapper](https://github.com/takari/maven-wrapper), which makes it easier to use Maven. It will automatically download the correct version of Maven before building the application.

Related questions:

- [What is the purpose of mvnw and mvnw.cmd files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38723833/what-is-the-purpose-of-mvnw-and-mvnw-cmd-files)